# The structure of the csv i get is incorect

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to create a new CSV from another with PHP .

The results i get is what i need, except the organisation of the CSV .

I don't want a header and i need to separate the fields by column.

I want to get something like this :

```
      A           B      C
T4004XDUHF210   14.55   40
```

I'm getting :

```
          A
article_id,2.50,availability

T4004XDUHF210,14.55,40

MSME10/1-ZS10,14.64,58

R3506XKIKT501,14.86,49

T3506XDUHF207,14.86,40

R4103504XKIKT602,14.86,40
```

My PHP Code :

```
$outputfp = fopen('new.csv', 'w');

if (($inputfp = fopen("temp/tmp/138702_fr.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

while (($data = fgetcsv($inputfp, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) {

        $line = array();
        // SKU
        $line[]=$data[1];
        // Price
        $price_calcul=(($data[4]*0.20)+$data[4])+2.5;
        $line[] = number_format($price_calcul,2); 
        // Quantity
        $line[]=$data[9];

        fputcsv($outputfp, $line);

        }

    // Clean up
    fclose($inputfp);
    fclose($outputfp);
}
```

So i don't need article_id,2.50,availability and i want tabs delimited.

Comment: You should tag the appropriate language.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean ?

Comment: i understand i taged PHP i forgot ^^

Comment: So then you don't want a CSV (the "CS" in CSV means "Comma Separated").  You want fixed sized fields or you want tab delimited?

Comment: I want just tab delimited (sorry for my explaination) , i'm from france ;) and i don't want article_id,2.50,availability

Answer (score 1):

I've noted the changes you need to make below:

```
<?php
$outputfp = fopen('new.csv', 'w');

if (($inputfp = fopen("temp/tmp/138702_fr.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $i = 0;            // <-- Add this line
    while (($data = fgetcsv($inputfp, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) {
        $i++;          // <-- Add this line

        if ($i == 1) { //
            continue;  // <-- Add these lines
        }              //

        $line = array();
        // SKU
        $line[]=$data[1];
        // Price
        $price_calcul=(($data[4]*0.20)+$data[4])+2.5;
        $line[] = number_format($price_calcul,2); 
        // Quantity
        $line[]=$data[9];

        fputcsv($outputfp, $line, "\t"); // <-- Change this line
    }

    // Clean up
    fclose($inputfp);
    fclose($outputfp);
}
?>
```

Comment: You're close, i'm not getting the first line, it's fine, i mean article_id,2.50,availability . But the fields are not separated, i want for instance T4004XDUHF210 (A) 14.55 (B) 40 (C) .

Comment: Look  at this picture : http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/653174starkoverflow.jpg

Comment: If the goal is to open it in Excel and have Excel automatically recognize that it is tab delimited, change the `.csv` extension of the output file to a `.tab` extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if i change the extension i will get the output empty. What should i do ?